# How to shuffle an array with duplicate items, but duplicates can't be back to back

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, shuffle

Given an array `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]`, is it possible to shuffle the array while preventing the duplicates to be next to each other?

For example:

- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4]` is an acceptable solution.
- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5]` is not an acceptable solution since `4` is next to another `4`

This seems like a simple question but after thinking about it, the solution seems complicated. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Where's the data coming from? What's the guarantee that this stays solvable? You commented beneath something about 3 dupes in 60items. What's the average/worst rate of duplicates?

Comment: I'm manipulating the data so it should always be solvable. Right now the most duplicates that could occur is 3 but that's subject to change in the future, could be more or less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the execution time of the algorithm, just shuffle a few times until you get the result you want

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];

const hasDublicateItems = (arr) => arr.some((v, i, a) => v === a[i+1]);

while (hasDublicateItems(arr)) 
  arr = arr.sort(() => (Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Not bad for small arrays with few duplicates, but my use case will have up to 3 duplicates and 60 total items. I'll try this for now and see how it works. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @BrandonBohach, So did you try this code in prod? What performance you get? Can you provide the worst input data for tests?

Comment: Seems to be working pretty nicely, no performance issues that I've noticed. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: 2 things: `() => Math.random() - .5` is sufficient, you don't need the ternary expression. But this "shuffle" doesn't create great results. You should use a better shuffle-function https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/6567275